# Я покладу тебе завтрак или Я положу тебе завтрак

Tags: грамотная-речь, разговорная-речь

Как правильно говорить : "Я  покладу тебе хлеб " или "Я положу тебе хлеб"?

Answer (score 2):

Правилен вариант "Я положу тебе хлеб". Просторечный глагол "покласть" фиксируется некоторыми словарями и допускается в речи литературных персонажей, однако употребляется он только в значении "положить (вещи куда-либо) *одну за другой*, погрузить".

Answer (score 0):

Никаких приставок перед словом "кладу" быть не может.